# Is there a way to use a topic with multiple partition as config.storage.topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have few 3 topics for config, offset and status. All 3 have same properties. All have partition as 3. So when I try to deploy distributed connector worker, I am getting

`"connector-config"supplied via the 'config.storage.topic' property is required to have a single partition in order to guarantee consistency of connector configurations, but found 3 partitions.`

is there any way to use topic with multiple partitions as config storage topic? or is there way to use something else like a DB or something for config storage?

The partition is set to minimum of 3 by admins. So we are not able to change that. Is there any work around for this?

I tried adding `CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_PARTITIONS` in K8 file, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Configs must be ordered, and therefore the topic is required to have a single partition, as the error says. Kafka Connect cannot use external configuration stores.

Sounds like your admins are confusing replication factor and partition count. There are many valid use cases for having a single partitioned topic